# Conditional replacement of a string in data frame

Tags: r

```
DF <- data.frame("ID" = c(901, 902, 903, 904, 909), "INT" = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1))

> DF
   ID INT
1 901   0
2 902   1
3 903   0
4 904   1
5 909   1
```

I want to replace "9" in the ID column when INT = 1, so, it should look like following:

```
 New_DF
   ID INT
1 901   0
2 802   1
3 903   0
4 804   1
5 809   1
```

I have tried this

```
if(DF$INT == "1") {
  gsub("^9", "8", DF$ID) 
}
```

It gives me the following error:

> Warning message:
>       In if (DF$INT == "1") { :
>         the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `ifelse()` function.

```
DF$ID <- ifelse(DF$INT == 1,  gsub("^9", "8", DF$ID), DF$ID)
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
DF %>% 
   mutate(ID=ifelse(INT==1,gsub("^9","8",ID),ID))
```

This will run the `gsub` on the rows where `DF$INT == 1`, and if it's not 1 then it will remain the same.

The `if()` function that you used:

```
if(DF$INT == "1") { }
```

is not intended to work on `data.frame`s. The `if()` function is used **only** to check if something (like a statement) is TRUE or FALSE. For example:

```
if(use_new_function == "on"){ 
    run_new_function() 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `log` to find the number of digits and then subtract 10 raised to the number of digits based if `INT` is `1`. This way, `ID` will still be `numeric`.

```
digits = floor(log(DF$ID, 10))
transform(DF, ID = ID - (10^digits) * (floor(ID/(10^digits)) == 9) * (INT))
#   ID INT
#1 901   0
#2 802   1
#3 903   0
#4 804   1
#5 809   1
```

Answer (score 1):

We could first find indices where `INT` is 1 and then use `sub` to replace the values at that indices.

```
inds <- DF$INT == 1
DF$ID[inds] <- as.integer(sub("^9", "8", DF$ID[inds]))

DF
#   ID INT
#1 901   0
#2 802   1
#3 903   0
#4 804   1
#5 809   1
```

Or we can also use `ifelse`

```
as.integer(ifelse(DF$INT == 1, sub("^9", "8", DF$ID), DF$ID))
#[1] 901 802 903 804 809
```

Comment: Nice  - the `object[ind] <- fun(object[ind])` logic doesn't seem popular any longer, but it's really useful.

Answer (score 1):

The `substring` can be used for assignment.  Create a logical index based on the 'INT' column and by checking if the first character of 'ID" is 9 ('i1'), then use `substring` for assigning the first character of 'ID' to '8'

```
i1 <- as.logical(DF$INT) & substr(DF$ID, 1, 1) =='9'
substring(DF$ID[i1], 1, 1) <- '8'
DF
#   ID INT
#1 901   0
#2 802   1
#3 903   0
#4 804   1
#5 809   1
```

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = c("901", "902", "903", "904", "909"), 
 INT = c(0, 
  1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

As in your example data `DF` both columns are *numeric* you can simply use

```
DF$ID[DF$INT==1] <- DF$ID[DF$INT==1] - 100
```

If the column `ID` is a *string* you can use `gsub` like:

```
DF$ID <- as.character(DF$ID)
DF$ID[DF$INT==1] <- gsub("^9", "8", DF$ID[DF$INT==1])
#   ID INT
#1 901   0
#2 802   1
#3 903   0
#4 804   1
#5 809   1
```

which places your `if(DF$INT == "1")` to a data subset `[DF$INT==1]`